# will remove paths in tsconfig automatically when I start the app

Tags: typescript

I using the CRA + Typescript to set up my project. And I also config the `paths` property in `tsconfig` file to use the absolute path.

Seems everything works fine after my configuration. But when I start my App using `npm run start` or run test. I find the `paths` property will be automatically removed.

here is the `tsconfig.json` file I configured.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

and I try to use like this way in the test file:

```js
import i18n from 'src/i18n/mocks';
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration? can someone help me? thks.

Comment: I find that's a remaining issue that CRA not support `compilerOptions.paths` yet. [https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5118](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5118) and also [https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5645#issuecomment-435201019](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5645#issuecomment-435201019)

Answer (score 5):

There's a workaround.

1. Create a new file "base-tsconfig.json" and put the `baseUrl` config and `paths` in there. Those won't be overwritten by CRA.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

2. Extend the main tsconfig.json file with your custom configuration

```
{
  "extends": "./base-tsconfig.json"
}
```

Read more here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5585

Comment: doesn't work for me, tsc seem to didn't find any option from the base-tsconfig.json file

Comment: It did not work for me either

Answer (score -2):

Remove paths and let the baseUrl as src.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

In that way, you will have the desired experience.

```js
// file is inside src folder
import path from 'file'
```